# rootViewController view property

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a question regarding `UIViewControllers`. If I have a view hierarchy that is  made of the following - view2 is subview of view1 and view3 is subview of view2 - . To get the view hierarchy my `rootViewController.view` property will be set to

```
rootViewController.view = view3;
```

what if view3 and view2 are on the same level. For example view2 and view3 are subviews of view1 how can I set my `rootViewController.view`?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayOfViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

//now you can take last viewcontroller from array and set that controller as root view controller like below

rootViewController.view = [arrayOfViewControllers lastObject];
```